# Примагнитить картинку ко 2 картинке. Js

Tags: javascript, математика

Есть 2 картинки, перемещающиеся по траектории эллипса. С двумя условиями: они перемещаются по разным эллипсам(они отличаются только радиусом. Можно сказать, что 1 эллипс находится во 2).

Код движения:

```js
this.x1 = this.x + ((this.radius - 8) * Math.sin(this.angle)) * Math.sin(0) + (1.4 * (this.radius - 8) * Math.cos(this.angle)) * Math.cos(0);

this.y1 = this.y + (1.3 * (this.radius - 32) * Math.cos(this.angle)) * Math.sin(0) + (1.3 * (this.radius - 32) * Math.sin(this.angle)) * Math.cos(0);

this.angle += 0.12;
```

Если известны координаты двух картинок, то как можно задать движение 2 картинки к 1?

Comment: Немного смутили `Math.sin(0)` и `Math.cos(0)`. Там всегда угол равен 0 ?

Comment: Напишите подробнее, что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Если хотите постепенно наложить одну картинку на другую, то можно использовать интерполяцию на отрезке `(x, y)-(x1, y1)`. К примеру, пусть степень близости задается числом `p из отрезка [0..1]`, тогда можно так: `newX = x+p*((x+x1)/2 - x); newY=y+p*((y+y1)/2 - y); newX1=x1+p*((x+x1)/2 - x1); newY1=y1+p*((y+y1)/2 - y1)` Таким образом, независимо от позиций картинок, они будут стягиваться друг к другу по мере роста `p` от `0 до 1`.

Comment: @Vladimir, мне надо примагнитить только внешнее тело, 2 должно оставаться на своей траектории

Comment: Тогда первое не трогаем и двигаем только 2е по направлению к 1му: `x1=x1+p*(x - x1); y1=y1+p*(y - y1)` Тут подразумевается, что (x1,y1) - координаты 2го тела. Если это не так, то, во всех формулах надо поменять местами x<-->x1, y <--> y1.

Comment: @Vladimir, спасибо)